# My apps keeps crashing when button is pressed and EditText is empty

Tags: android

I've tried lot of things found here, but it keeps crashing. I wanna know what do i need to add in order to show a Toast message when button is clicked and EditText is empty.

INFO: The app is supposed to send the two values in the EditText's to another activity, showing Toast's in the following exceptions:the first value higher than 6; the second value higher than (firstvalue*14); and if the fields are empty (which is my problem)

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView saludo_bienvenida;
    EditText et1_creditos;
    EditText et2_faltas;
    Button boton_ingresar;
    Button boton_info;
    String numero_creditos;
    String numero_faltas_actuales;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        saludo_bienvenida = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saludo_bienvenida);

        et1_creditos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1_numero_creditos);

        et2_faltas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext2_numero_faltas);

        boton_ingresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_ingresar);

        boton_info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_info);

        if (boton_ingresar != null) {
            boton_ingresar.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        if (boton_info != null) {
            boton_info.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        et1_creditos.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        et2_faltas.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.boton_ingresar:
                numero_creditos = et1_creditos.getText().toString();
                numero_faltas_actuales = et2_faltas.getText().toString();
                int numero_creditos1 = Integer.parseInt(numero_creditos);
                int numero_faltas_actuales1 = Integer.parseInt(numero_faltas_actuales);
                int o = numero_creditos1 * 14;



                if (numero_creditos1>6) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ingrese un número válido de créditos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (numero_faltas_actuales1 > o){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El número de faltas ingresadas es mayor que el número de horas del curso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Resultados.class);
                    intent.putExtra("numero_creditos",numero_creditos);
                    intent.putExtra("numero_faltas_actuales",numero_faltas_actuales);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.boton_info:
                Intent informacion = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Informacion.class);
                startActivity(informacion);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the log:

```
06-17 01:36:17.419 2738-2738/absence_counter.app.jorgepasco.com.absencecounter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                             Process: absence_counter.app.jorgepasco.com.absencecounter, PID: 2738
                                                                                             java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                                                 at absence_counter.app.jorgepasco.com.absencecounter.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:60)
                                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Did read the logcat? Found the exception given? Maybe a nullPointerException

Comment: Does the string you get from your EditText [contain a parsable integer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks you for your log !

You can see on your log that you have a problem when you parseInt. You try to parseInt an empty String.

So when the user do not write anything, you have to set a default value yourself.
You can do something like that before your parse:

```
if(numero_creditos.equals(""))
     numero_creditos = "0";
```

But if I were you, I would force the user to right directly an integer

Comment: And of course, you have to do the same with "numero_faltas_actuales"

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank so much, really.

Answer (score 0):

Please, show us your log box.

Perhaps the app crash because you don't have any default case in your switch case. So if v.getId() is not what you think, it will crash.

Simply, add that at the end of your switch case:

```
switch(v.getId()){
    case: ...
    case: ...
    default: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"v.getId = " + v.getId());
}
```

But I would be easier for me to solve your problem with your log box !

Answer (score 0):

`et1_creditos.getText()` can maybe send a null value. Then null.toString() has no sense because null does not have toString().

try:

```
String creditos = et1_creditos.getText()
if(creditos != null){
   //stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is failing on this line.

```
        int numero_creditos1 = Integer.parseInt(numero_creditos);
```

If your numeor_creditos is empty it won't be integer.
Try

```
int numero_creditos1;
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(numero_creditos){
    numero_creditos1 = 0;
} else {
    numero_creditos1 = Integer.parseInt(numero_creditos);
}
```